# postgreSQL how to convert multiple rows from a table to an array of JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

`ROW_TO_JSON` function in postgres converts a row of a table to a JSON object.

```
select row_to_json(result) from (select * from employee) as result;
select row_to_json(result) from (select * from student) as result;
```

Gives me three rows:

```
{"salary":null,"age":65,"address":null,"id":111,"name":"NAME"}
{"salary":null,"age":21,"address":null,"id":222,"name":"SURNAME"}
{"dob":"1997-03-02","name":"Mediocore","passed":true,"id":555}
```

The first two rows are from `employee` table whereas the last row is from `student` table.

What If I want to put the entire resultset from a single table in an array of JSON objects ?
eg.

`[{"salary":null,"age":65,"address":null,"id":111,"name":"NAME"}, {"salary":null,"age":21,"address":null,"id":222,"name":"SURNAME"}]`as a single row instead of two separate rows.

Is there something equivalent to `TABLE_TO_JSON` ?

Comment: what version you run?..

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6 with pgAdmin 4 v4

Comment: ah, then @a_horse_with_no_name gave best answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but this looks like `json_agg` should do it.

You also don't need the derived table:

```
select json_agg(row_to_json(employee)) 
from employee;
```

Comment: row_to_json is first json function, how did you know OPs not on 9.2?